# Where can I read the ANSI terminal standard?

Tags: terminal, standards

I'd thinking about creating my own Terminal Emulation library, and I'd like to start by trying to get the latest standard for ANSI terminals. I know there are a lot resources out there, but I'd like to read the actual standard if I can.

If the standard costs "a lot of money" (for me, more than $25) to acquire, what's the next best (most complete) description I can find?

Comment: Just a shot: is this what might be looking for? https://webstore.iec.ch/preview/info_isoiec6429%7Bed3.0%7Den.pdf

Comment: Voting to close due to the clearly articulated [requests for off-site resources are off topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) clause *(a.k.a. StackOverflow is not a search engine)*, and one has to follow the rules and all that.  But in terms of search engine advice, "ANSI terminal PDF" finds a few things, e.g. ftp://epsfiles.intermec.com/eps_files/eps_man/977055005J.pdf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found what I'm looking for. 
According to WikiPedia's [ANSI escape code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#History), the standard adopted was ECMA-48, the document is available at [www.ecma-international.org Ecma-048.pdf](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-048.pdf)

Comment: Actually ISO-6429 is "the" standard, while ECMA-48 republishes the same content.  The latter is free for downloading, and the former is not.

Comment: It looks like ISO-6429 "adopts" the ECMA-48 as the standard.  So, ECMA-48 appears to be the definitive source for my purposes.